# How to extract a "registration" URL from a mail content

Tags: java, email

I am successful in reading the content of the gmail-email using "JAVAMail" and I am able to store it in a string. Now I want to get a specific registration URL from the content (String). How can I do this, The String contains plenty of tags and href but I want to extract only the URL that is provided in a hyper link on a word " click here" that exist in the below mentioned statement

```
"Please <a class="h5" href="https://newstaging.mobilous.com/en/user-register/******" target="_blank">click here</a> to complete your registration".
```

on the hyper link "click here" the url

href="https://newstaging.mobilous.com/en/user-register/******" target="_blank"

I  have tried this by using the following code

```
package email;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

public class emailAccess {

    public static void check(String host, String storeType, String user,
             String password) 
          {
             try {

             //create properties field
             Properties properties = new Properties();

             properties.put("mail.imap.host",host);
             properties.put("mail.imap.port", "993");
             properties.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
             properties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
               properties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
               properties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port",String.valueOf(993));
             Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

             //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
             Store store = emailSession.getStore("imap");

             store.connect(host, user, password);

             //create the folder object and open it
             Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
             emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

             // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
             Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
             System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);
                int n=messages.length;
                for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
                Message message = messages[i];
                ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
                if(message.getSubject().contains("Thank you for signing up for AppExe")){
                String desc=message.getContent().toString();

              // System.out.println(desc);
              Pattern linkPattern = Pattern.compile(" <a\\b[^>]*href=\"[^>]*>(.*?)</a>",  Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE|Pattern.DOTALL);
               Matcher pageMatcher = linkPattern.matcher(desc);

               while(pageMatcher.find()){
                   links.add(pageMatcher.group());
               } 
                }else{
                System.out.println("Email:"+ i + " is not a wanted email");
                }
                for(String temp:links){
                if(temp.contains("user-register")){
                    System.out.println(temp);
                }
                }

                /*System.out.println("---------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
                System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
                System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
                System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());*/

             }
             //close the store and folder objects
             emailFolder.close(false);
             store.close();

             } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
          }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String host = "imap.gmail.com";
         String mailStoreType = "imap";
         String username = "rameshakur@gmail.com";
         String password = "*****";

         check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);


    }

}
```

On executing I got the out put as

< class="h5" href="https://newstaging.mobilous.com/en/user-register/******" target="_blank">

How can I extract only the href value i.e. https://newstaging.mobilous.com/en/user-register/******

Please suggest, thanks.

Comment: When you say "I have tried using the split"... you'll get a much better response here if you show what you tried, and what the result of that was, and why that result isn't what you want.

Comment: I have updated the code that I used to fetch the required URL in to array and also edited my question accordingly. Please go through it once thanks

Comment: I'd say you change your regex to exclude 'href' and other unwanted parts, or (better) use grouping around the url-part of the regex and provide the specific group nr when calling `pageMatcher.group()`.

Comment: @user2326333 Did you try the code from my answer below?  Just replace  the 5 line with what I have below (or really just change the 2 lines that are different), and it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close.  You're using group(), but you've got a couple issues.  Here's some code that should work, replacing just a bit of what you've got:

```
Pattern linkPattern = Pattern.compile(" <a\\b[^>]*href=\"([^\"]*)[^>]*>(.*?)</a>",  Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE|Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher pageMatcher = linkPattern.matcher(desc);
while(pageMatcher.find()){
    links.add(pageMatcher.group(1));
}
```

All I did was to change your pattern so it explicitly looks for the end-quote of the href attribute, then wrapped the portion of the pattern that was the string you're looking for in parentheses.

I also added an argument to the `pageMather.group()` method, as it needs one.

Tell you the truth, you could probably just use this pattern instead (along with the `.group(1)` change):

```
Pattern linkPattern = Pattern.compile("href=\"([^\"]*)",  Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE|Pattern.DOTALL);
```